# Haskell: Get one of alternative type

Tags: haskell

Say I have a type such as:

```
data Cell = Empty | Full
```

Does Haskell provide a simple way to nondeterministically call one or the other of these constructors? Basically I am trying to randomize which constructor gets called, e.g. `[CellOfSomeType | i <- [1..somerange]]`

Comment: Hint: `Empty` and `Full` are values, not functions you need to call (like in OOP).

Comment: Ok, then how to randomly get one of the values?

Comment: Use the [`random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random) package or alternatives. Excuse me for being so short on words, I'd provide a bit more help but I have shortage of time.

Comment: I am a Haskell beginner and `System.Random` has frustrated me with its `IO a` typing stuff - was hoping there was a built-in way.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a built-in way but `random` _is_ idiomatic.
`IO a` is important for Haskell's purity. Perhaps you can look up *why* we want a functionally pure language and you could learn to love it as the vast majority of Haskellers do (this is a big reason why a lot of us are even here, it's really a good thing).

Comment: I'm on board with the Haskell train, I just don't understand how to get the behavior I need out of an `IO Int` for example. Fully aware this is a problem of my own understanding atm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137804/discussion-between-mastermastic-and-zzu).

Answer (score 3):

Just get a random bit and set the value to `Full` or `Empty` based on that bit. For example:

```
import System.Random
```

You seem to be talking about `System.Random`, but this sort of information should be included in the question.

```
data Cell = Full | Empty
          deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Enum)
```

I derived `Enum` for use with ranged randoms. Now we are going to define an instance for the `Random` class so you can use a couple of the common libraries to generate random values of type `Cell`.  The `Random` class requires we at least define `random` and `randomR` methods.

```
instance Random Cell where
  random g = let (a,g') = random g
                 val = if a then Full else Empty
             in (val,g')
  randomR (l,h) g = let (a,g') = randomR (fromEnum l, fromEnum h) g
                    in (toEnum a, g')
```

Since your type is identical to `Bool` we can just generate a random bool (a bit) and select one of your two constructors.  The ranged randoms are a little more of a nuisance but we just generate an Int somewhere between the lower bound and upper bounds requested then acquire the constructor matching that Int value.